# What is the problem with my sql query?

Tags: sql, mysql

What is the problem with my sql query ?

```
UPDATE template SET template = template . "hello"
```

Comment: there is no dot operator in mysql. use concat() function

Comment: @Brad I wouldn't have necessarily removed the PHP tag, it's unclear whether or not he's constructing a SQL query in PHP.

Comment: @Daniel: Irrelevant, this isn't in PHP code, surrounded by PHP code, or does it affect PHP (well, at least the payload, maybe not so much the result). I could ask for help with a java applet and apply a PHP tag because I have it on my PHP-based website; does that incur relevance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concatenation in MySQL uses a `+` i believe, not a `.` (that's php). Alternatively, you could use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE template SET template=CONCAT(template,'hello');
```

Comment: @MarkSQLDev: Thus the alternatively. ;-)

Comment: You're right, I missed that at first - you covered it in effect.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you making this query?  If it's just in MySQL, they don't use `.` as the concatenation operator like PHP does.  Look into [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) instead if this is just a SQL query.

It's unclear from your question and your tags whether or not we should help you with PHP syntax or MySQL's SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE template SET template = template . "hello"

update tablename
set fieldname=new field value
```

[1] template  is a table name or field name? if fieldname then you have to use  below syntex:

```
**update tablename
set template = concat(template,'.', 'hello')**
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is replace all of the rows in template to = "hello" then

```
UPDATE template 
SET template = 'hello'
```

(Edit replaced quotes with single quotes)