# use of period(.) while updating wamp password

Tags: mysql

While updating the WAMP password we use an `UPDATE` query:

```
update mysql.user set password = password('somepassword') where user = 'root';
```

Alternatively [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503073/what-is-the-problem-with-my-sql-query).

Here many feel we cannot use the dot(.) operator (mainly used in PHP) and use `concat` or `+` instead.

But in this `UPDATE` scenario—which I mentioned above—I was unable to use `concat` or `+` either.

So under  what scnerio should we use `.` and `+` or in other words what is the main difference between `.` and `+` in mysql

Comment: Wait, a minute. Are you talking about the `.` in `mysql.user`? That is absolutely the correct way to denote `table.column` in SQL.  PHP is irrelevant. You have no concatenations happening here.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski ,Ya i am confused about . (dot) in mysql and not php

Comment: @JakeGould, ya .(dot) in mysql.user

Comment: Have a look at the [MySQL documentation on identifier qualifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html). The use of `.` in `database_name.table_name.column_name` is described there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` in this:

```
mysql.user
```

Basically means to do something to the table `user` in the database `mysql`. In other words, `mysql.user` equates to `[database].[table]`. It is *not concatenation* but rather simply the way MySQL syntax works. Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

The question you linked to was about using `.` to concatenate in PHP a value that would go into a MySQL query string. Completely different thing.